# Dropzonejs on WordPress with ajax uploads, i can't make mockfile working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, dropzone.js

I have implemented dropzonejs on WordPress successfully and and i got everything working until the part i need to preload images into dropzone which are already uploaded on the server. 
I have created custom template for creating new posts and edit posts on frontend. 
When creating posts everything works fine since Dropzone only upload new files, but when editing posts i need to pull into dropzone files that are already uploaded to the post.

From all of the instructions out there i couldn't find any solution that would work for me.

Here is a complete script with a dropzone (the script is directly into template php so there is a bit of php mixing inside javascript)

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
// Dropzone file uploader
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone ("#media-uploader", {
    url: dropParam.upload,
    autoProcessQueue: true,
    parallelUploads: 1,
    uploadMultiple: false,
    maxFilesize: 3,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxFiles: 10,
    success: function (file, response) {
        file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
        file['attachment_id'] = response; // push the id for future reference
        $('#uploaded-media').append( $('<input type="hidden" name="media-ids[]" id="media-ids[]" class="media-ids" value="' + response +'">') );
    },
    error: function (file, response) {
        file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
    },
    // update the following section is for removing image from library
    removedfile: function(file) {
        var attachment_id = file.attachment_id;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: dropParam.delete,
            data: {
                media_id : attachment_id
            }
        });
        $('input.media-ids[type=hidden]').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() === attachment_id) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
        var _ref;
        return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
    }
});
<?php if ($media != '') {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($media) ; $i++) {
        $media_info[$i]['src'] = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $media[$i] );
        $media_info[$i]['size'] = filesize( get_attached_file( $media[$i] ) );
        $media_info[$i]['name'] = basename($media_info[$i]['src'][0]); 
    ?>
        var mockFile = { name: "<?php echo $media_info[$i]['name'] ?>", size: <?php echo $media_info[$i]['size'] ?> };
        myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
        myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, "<?php echo $media_info[$i]['src'][0] ?>");
        myDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
    <?php } ?>
    var existingFileCount = <?php echo $i ?>; // The number of files already uploaded
    myDropzone.options.maxFiles = myDropzone.options.maxFiles - existingFileCount;
<?php } ?>

});
</script>
```

So this actually get the images from the server, get the info of the images and put them into dropzone field.

The problem is, when i try to remove the image from dropzone, the script doesn't respond to ajax remove function i don't see response in my firebug console. Actually the dropzone stops responding on further actions (removing or adding a new image)

EDIT:
I think what i am actually missing is `file['attachment_id'] = response; // push the id for future reference` part when creating `mockfile`.

Answer (score -1):

So i got it working, after 2 days looking for solution i got it only shortly after i posted here for a question. It always happens like that.

To make it working i needed to change 2 things. First i added `attachment_id` to preloaded images

```
var mockFile = { name: "<?php echo $media_info[$i]['name'] ?>", size: <?php echo $media_info[$i]['size'] ?>, attachment_id: <?php echo $media[$i] ?> };
```

And second it seems that this `attachment_id` from preloaded images is a string so in looking for input field to be deleted i had to change it to check for equal value instead of identical value.

```
    $('input.media-ids[type=hidden]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == attachment_id) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Care to explain why down voting ?